# mysql MATCH AGAINST with LIMIT

Tags: mysql, limit, match-against

everybody
I'm querying a huge table, trying to find the first 100 most recent record matching a town (in this example Venice): **select *id* from *table_name* where MATCH(*column_name*) AGAINST (*string_to_search*) order by date_created DESC limit 100**.
It definitely ignores the LIMIT instruction and the query is so slow.
Can someone help me in setting a **LIMIT** in a query with a **MATCH AGAINST** in where condition?
thanks a lot!

Comment: If limit is ignored and the result contains more than 100 rows, then please file a [bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com)

Comment: actually, LIMIT is NOT ignored and I get 100 rows but the search in done on the complete table and it doesn't stop at the 100th row found. that's why the query is so slow either setting LIMIT or without setting it